# Erro :An exception occurred while initializing the database. See the InnerException for details

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Alguém poderia me ajudar nesse ero que sempre me deparo com ele e depois de inúmeras tentativas, eu não consigo achar esse erro, eu estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em MVC 3 explorando mais essa parte do *Code First*. Alguém poderia me ajudar nisso?

Segue o código, e o erro em que dá assim que compilo a solução:

```
public class ClienteController : Controller
{
    private BancoContexto db = new BancoContexto();

    public ViewResult Index()
    {
            return View(db.Clientes.ToList());
    }


    public ViewResult Details(int id)
    {
        //Cliente cliente = db.Clientes.Find(id);
        Cliente cliente = db.Clientes.Include("Vendas")
             .Include("Produtos")
            .Single(p => p.IDCliente == id);
        return View(cliente);
    }


    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    } 



    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Cliente cliente)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Clientes.Add(cliente);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");  
        }

        return View(cliente);
    }


    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        Cliente cliente = db.Clientes.Find(id);
        return View(cliente);
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Cliente cliente)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(cliente).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(cliente);
    }

    public ActionResult Delete(int id)
    {
        Cliente cliente = db.Clientes.Find(id);
        return View(cliente);
    }


    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {            
        Cliente cliente = db.Clientes.Find(id);
        db.Clientes.Remove(cliente);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        db.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

}

Segue anexo o erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]